# Win-Vista w/VMWare Player w/Ubuntu Server 12.04; IE on host can't connect to image

Tags: windows-vista, vmware-player, ubuntu-server

1. Created brand new image of Ubuntu Server 12.04

   2. Installed Apache2
   3. Applied all updates / upgrades
   4. ifconfig shows IP aaa.bbb.c.ddd
   5. Using 'Bridged' setting in VMPlayer
   6. Using IE on host, enter http://aaa.bbb.c.ddd/ results in the
      following pop-up

'Do you want to open or save aaa.bbb.c.ddd (634 bytes) from aaa.bbb.c.ddd?'

- I checked 'Network Connections|Local Area Connection|Properties and
  checked the boxes beside VMware.
- Saw some website that said I needed to enable php in IE, but wasn't
  clear if that is causing my problem.

I appreciate any help you can provide!!

Comment: Since you resolved your problem, why not post your solution as an answer to the question and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

(As [posted](https://superuser.com/revisions/549643/2) by [trevil](https://superuser.com/users/197422/trevil))

I solved the problem by doing the following:

- Reinstalled LAMP on the Ubuntu Server [but I don't think this is what cured the problem]
- Went to 'Network and Sharing Center' and saw the 'Unidentified Network', then clicked on 'Customize' and saw the box for 'Location Type: Public' was checked. I changed that to 'Private'

Now when I open IE on the Vista host and enter the IP address, I correctly see the screen that I was expecting. (I was creating this VM to play with Omeka, so now I get the Omeka config screen.)